# java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: insufficient funds for gas * price + value when deploying smart contracts

Tags: solidity, web3j, java

I am trying to deploy smart contract using web3j.
My code is as follows:

```
 @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() throws Exception {
        Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/2a42af3ce74e407cae9e20a7e7001ddb"));
        String walletId = "97a0987c270cd6cfa77972b83026eb56524857c5";
        String walletSource = "resources/testnet-keystore/UTC--2018-09-26T00-58-36.238000000Z--" + walletId + ".json";
        System.out.println(walletSource);
        Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials("admin1234", walletSource);
        System.out.println(credentials);
        ProofOfExistence contract = ProofOfExistence.deploy(web3j, credentials, ProofOfExistence.GAS_PRICE,ProofOfExistence.GAS_LIMIT).send();;
           String contractAddress = contract.getContractAddress();
           return "Contract is deployed at address: " + contractAddress;
    }
```

I have started my geth console.When i try running the contract. I get funds insufficient error.I am using spring boot to run my applications.
Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Are you sure you have Ether in the account and that you are synced up to date?

Comment: if you can post the code of your smart contract, that would be better.

Comment: I used the following code to run geth "geth --rpcapi personal,db,eth,net,web3 --rpc --testnet --fast". How do i check Ether in the account and that you are synced up to date? @LauriPeltonen

Comment: my smart contract code is : pragma solidity ^0.4.15;
// Proof of Existence contract, version 1
contract ProofOfExistence {

  bytes32 public proof;

  function notarize(string document) {
    proof = proofFor(document);
  }

  function proofFor(string document) constant returns (bytes32) {
    return sha256(document);
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I had not funded my account with ether using rinkeby  faucet. After funding account, it is giving me the expected output. thank you for the help!!